# MySQL - How to know if query is using FTS index

Tags: mysql

As the title says, how would you know if a query uses FTS index or not?

normally it shows `using index condition`.

my query was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE MATCH(news_title,news_keywords) AGAINST ('news') 
AND news_date_created BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
```

and executed `EXPLAIN` and gave me:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+----------+--------------------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type     | possible_keys            | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+----------+--------------------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news  | NULL       | fulltext | news_date_idx,news_title | news_title |       0 | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Ft_hints: sorted |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+----------+--------------------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------------------------+
```

I don't know if it's using the index or not. It just says it is using `where and ft_hints`.

Comment: As far as I know, if you use `MATCH ... AGAINST` and there's not an appropriate index it just throws an error. Unlike regular queries, this isn't a piece of data that can be obtained without an index.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález No, this is not entirely correct.

Comment: @Shadow I'd appreciate an example on that. Can MySQL search for "house of commons" and find "common house" with a FT index?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes it can, just be sure not to put double quotes  in the `AGAINST` clause, putting in the double quotes would consider the words as whole. So `AGAINST ('common house')`  or `AGAINST ('house common')`, not `AGAINST ('"common house"')`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant **without** a full-text index, not "with" :(

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the explain result's `key` column, that lists the index(es) used. In this particular case `news_title` index was used. If this is your fulltext index, then it was used.

Also, note, that apart from [fulltext search in Boolean mode on myiasm tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-restrictions.html), all searches require a matching fulltext index to be present:

> The MATCH() column list must match exactly the column list in some FULLTEXT index definition for the table, unless this MATCH() is IN BOOLEAN MODE on a MyISAM table. For MyISAM tables, boolean-mode searches can be done on nonindexed columns, although they are likely to be slow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I think You're right, because what you have said was similar on this link : [link](https://www.percona.com/live/europe-amsterdam-2015/sites/default/files/slides/Query%20Optimization%3A%20From%200%20to%2010%20(and%20up%20to%205.7).pdf) at page 23